# Solaris vim end key

Tags: vim, solaris, xterm

A simple question: why with solaris 10 on vim pressing end key
produce F?

This is what appened pressing end

```
This is a text file,i will press "end key"

    F
    F
    F
    F
:(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found

```
# For some reason home and end keys are not mapping properly.
# Home key
imap <esc>OH <esc>0i
cmap <esc>OH <home>
nmap <esc>OH 0
# End key
nmap <esc>OF $
imap <esc>OF <esc>$a
cmap <esc>OF <end>
```

http://ianrolfe.livejournal.com/39474.html

Answer (score 1):

With Solaris 10, you're probably running either xterm or gnome-terminal.  For xterm, it has xterm patch #196, and a slightly-patched X11R6 xterm.

vim gets the terminal information from the terminal database.  The `xterm` definition lacks a definition for the home/end keys.  Here is what it looks like in terminfo format:

```
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/lib/terminfo/x/xterm
xterm|vs100|xterm terminal emulator,
        am, km, mir, msgr, xenl,
        cols#80, it#8, lines#65,
        acsc=``aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~,
        bel=^G, blink=\E[5m, bold=\E[1m, clear=\E[H\E[2J,
        cr=\r, csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=\b,
        cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=\n, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C,
        cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\E[A,
        dch=\E[%p1%dP, dch1=\E[P, dl=\E[%p1%dM, dl1=\E[M,
        ed=\E[J, el=\E[K, el1=\E[1K$<3>, enacs=\E(B\E)0,
        home=\E[H, ht=\t, hts=\EH, ich=\E[%p1%d@, ich1=\E[@,
        il=\E[%p1%dL, il1=\E[L, ind=\n, ka1=\EOq, ka3=\EOs,
        kb2=\EOr, kbs=\b, kc1=\EOp, kc3=\EOn, kcub1=\EOD,
        kcud1=\EOB, kcuf1=\EOC, kcuu1=\EOA, kent=\EOM,
        kf0=\E[21~, kf1=\E[11~, kf10=\EOx, kf2=\E[12~,
        kf3=\E[13~, kf4=\E[14~, kf5=\E[15~, kf6=\E[17~,
        kf7=\E[18~, kf8=\E[19~, kf9=\E[20~, rc=\E8, rev=\E[7m,
        ri=\EM, rmacs=^O, rmkx=\E[?1l\E>, rmso=\E[m,
        rmul=\E[m,
        rs1=\E>\E[1;3;4;5;6l\E[?7h\E[m\E[r\E[2J\E[H, rs2=@,
        sc=\E7,
        sgr=\E[0%?%p1%p6%|%t;1%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;m%?%p9%t^>
        sgr0=\E[m, smacs=^N, smkx=\E[?1h\E=, smso=\E[7m,
        smul=\E[4m, tbc=\E[3g,
```

If the terminal description had home/end keys, those would be listed as **`khome`** and **`kend`**, respectively.

Furthermore, the initialization string **`rs1`** turns on application mode for the *cursor keys* (which can include the 6-key editing keypad with the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys).  That makes them send <kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>`O`</kbd> prefix.

vim doesn't know anything about that information, since it just uses what it can get from the terminal database.  When it sees a sequence of characters **not** in the terminal database, it tries to interpret that one character at a time.  The <kbd>escape</kbd> character terminates insert mode, but <kbd>`O`</kbd> "opens" (begins an insertion), and you get the final character of the key, e.g., **`H`** or **`F`**.  Repeatedly pressing the key gets one **`F`** per press (leaving you in insert-mode after pressing the key).

The proper fix would be to repair the terminal description, avoiding the need for mappings in your `.vimrc`, e.g.,

```
infocmp >foo
vi foo
....adding this line (with a leading tab character):
        khome=\EOH, kend=\EOF,
sudo tic foo
```

Further reading:

- [Why can't I use the home/end keys?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_pc_style) (XTerm FAQ)
- [PC-Style Function Keys](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-PC-Style-Function-Keys) (XTerm Control Sequences)